# View.GONE via Databinding won't work

Tags: android, android-databinding

I try to dynamically set a visibility in my app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/bordersize_big">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listitem_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/fingersize"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_icon_filecard"
            android:visibility="@{View.GONE}"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
```

but the image is still visible, if i set `android:visibility="gone"` it is gone, what's wrong with my databinding?

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(listItemResource, null);
```

Comment: Please post how you are inflating this layout.

Comment: i've added the code

Comment: You should change it to, View v = DataBindingUtil.inflate(vi, listItemResource,null).getRoot(); something like this:

Answer (score 1):

If you are using data binding items inside a RecyclerView or Fragment adapter, you may prefer to use:

```
ListItemBinding binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, viewGroup, false);
```

**or**

```
ListItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
```

Then

```
View v = binding.getRoot()
```

You can go through this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-adding-some-variability-1fe001b3abcc)

Answer (score 0):

I all my projects i don't use databinding like that bacause it`s redundant. You dont need to import the View class to apply the visibility in one layout, you can do it directly:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/listitem_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/fingersize"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_icon_filecard"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
```

As you can see in the oficial documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

This import tag works when you have a condition to check (like true or false), not directly

```
<TextView
   android:text="@{user.lastName}"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:visibility="@{user.isAdult ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

Comment: i have a condition, but i simplified the example for my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
 LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 View v = vi.inflate(listItemResource, null);
```

Make sure to bind it in your ViewHolder constructor, assuming your layout name is list_item

```
ListItemBinding binding = DatabindingUtil.bind(v);
```

Here `v` is the `View` object you have created for your layout.